# What is the meaning of count in timer class for embedded programming in C and C++?

Tags: c++, c, embedded

I am studying embedded programming using the book [Programming Embedded Systems in C and C++](http://www.electronique-mixte.fr/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/Programmation-des-syst%C3%A8mes-embarqu%C3%A9s-.pdf)

I have two questions about some description in the book. Could you please take few minutes to give an explanation?

1. page 102, "This value represents the number of ticks that will be remaining in the software timer once all previous timers in the list have expired."

   Q:I do not understand what the count is used for and why there is a condition: once all previous timers in the list have expired...
2. page 103, "The second and third timers in the list both happen to expire at the same time, though the third timer will have been running for 10 times longer."

   Q: I do not understand why the second and third timer in the list both happen to expire at the same time.

Your feedback will be very helpful and appreciated!

Comment: You should include the relevant code in your question.

Comment: @ vijoc Please check my question carefully. This is not a question about code.

Comment: Surely there must be more context to your question than the sentences you've included. If it's not code, fine, but going with just one sentence is not feasible. I'm betting not many people are willing to download a PDF file and search for the context there.

Comment: @affeto actually your question is only about code, you should paste relevant code pieces here in order for the others understand the context. [This link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) will help you understand what we mean.

Comment: I cannot copy whole paragraph and paste here... I give a link, anybody can open it without download file. Also I give the page related with my questions. I believe the people good in this area can understand my question well. I am just looking for people who is skilled with embedded programming and has patient to read my questions and give me an answer.

Comment: On this site questions should be self contained. That is they should be understood and answerable only from reading the contents of the question. External links should be only extra information and should not condition the understanding of the question. As such I vote to close this question.

Comment: There is a site policy that external resources should not be needed but the question must be able to stand on its own. Links tend to die over time and SO seeks to preserve content over a long period of time. So please do not use links to code or other external resources. Especially not if the source is proprietary material, which might be the case here.

Comment: `affeto` says, `"I cannot copy whole paragraph and paste here.."`; I try to open the link, and try to copy the code. it is working. It is good practice to copy code and share for reference, and additionally you could provide link for reference. If you provide inline code with indentation, you would get answer quickly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) the `count` is number of milliseconds that are remaining for the timer to expire. This time seems to be relative to the previous timer and gets decremented every millisecond only for the topmost timer. Other timers' `count` value remains untouched in the ISR.

2) because when second timer expires (its `count` goes down to zero) then also next timers in linked list are checked and every timer with `count` equal to zero is considered as expired.